# Compatible ESC's with brushless 3 phase motors

Tags: motor, brushless-motor

Am trying to find the right ESC for the following two motors

http://www.e-fliterc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=EFLM30180MDFA#quickFeatures

http://www.e-fliterc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=EFLM3032DFA

Can't figure out which of the ESC's listed on the site would be best? Are there alternative (cheaper or better?) options?

Comment: To make this question more useful, consider copying the relevant motor (and ESC) specs from the linked pages into the question itself.  A good answer will explain how to read those specs and make the right decision.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the second, I see 62 amps continuous, 75 max burst, you want a brushless speed controler that can handle that, assuming you plan on using the full power of the motor. So, from that vendor; http://www.e-fliterc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=EFLA1080B

It takes some looking, but the first motor is a replacement for a kit. That kit comes with a 5 amp speed controler/receiver combo - so you would need a 5 amp brushless speed control. http://www.e-fliterc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=EFLA1005

That is quite a difference between the 2, power wise. You need to think about physical size and power requirements. Then I'd recommend cheap chinese verson instead; 
[hobbyking](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__517__59__Brushless_Motors-Outrunners_by_size.html)

Just remember, brushless motors need brushless speed controlers. other than that, match up potential amp draw to speed controller capability. Choose batteries based on intended length of runtime. The battery C rating indicated how much current it can deliver. A 1000mah battery rated at 20C can deliver 20 amps.